# Play Flac files on website

Tags: html, web, audio-player, flac

Is there a way to play Flac files on a website, preferably using HTML5 and/or jQuery?

Comment: sure, find a player that all browsers supports and has flac decode support. good luck!

Comment: Yes you can see [Audiocogs](http://audiocogs.org/) for example, or a [proof of concept](https://github.com/soyuka/audiocogs) here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any in-browser Flac player. But, if you are after a loseless file format, you can consider   [mp3HD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3HD), which is also loseless, like Flac, but is backwards compatible with mp3, which means that any mp3 player can play it.

Comment: mp3HD is only backward compatbile in it's lossy layer. You will not get lossless quality on a legacy decoder.